# how to call a sub with input between the parenthesis vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to call a sub from within another sub.  The problem is there is a variable in the event handler that appears nowhere else in the code. I think it is an array of data fed by an API. the variable in the event handler parenthesis is called 'positions'. the syntax inside the event handler parenthesis is:

```
ByVal positions as X.API.UpdateList
```

Comment: You don't need to use the `Call` keyword anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't code vb.net but if you are using `ByVal` you are actually referencing the value
of the variable `positions` to another variable in you main sub that holds the same data.
So try calling the Private Sub like this:

```
Call update(positions)
```

Take note that `positions` must be declared with the same data type in your main sub like this.

```
Dim positions as X.API.UpdateList
```

And of course it holds your  required value for use in your private sub.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please see the revised post above. I understand your suggestion but I can't figure out how to Handle the poPositions bar above as it seems to b some sort of array fed by the API. I whsh there was an easy way to place that `byval` expression outside the parenthesis. But because it is connected to the API I can't figure out what the syntax is supposed to be.

Comment: I can't figure out why you want to use the event handler in the first place. Why not just calling the sub procedure just as @L42 suggested.